# R is plotting y axis upside down. How to flip rightside up?

Tags: r, plot, axis

I've inherited this R code that plots a simple line graph. However, it does it so that the y axis values are plotted downwards below 0 (plots it in the 4th quadrant with 0 at the top and +3600 at the bottom). I want to plot the data right-side up (1st quadrant) so the y axis data goes from 0 up to +3600 at the top like a typical grade-school plot.

I've tried ylim = rev(y) but it returns an error...
I've also tried flipping the seq() command but no luck there.

```
list.vlevel = numeric(9) # placeholder
plot(
  rep(0, length(list.vlevel)),
  seq(1, length(list.vlevel)),
  type = "n",
  xlim = biaslim,
  axes = F,
  main = paste(list.var.bias[vv], list.score.bias[vv]),
  xlab = "",
  ylab = ""
)

abline(h = seq(1, length(list.vlevel)),
       lty = 3,
       col = 8)
axis(2,
     labels = list.vlevel,
     at = seq(length(list.vlevel), 1, -1),
     las = 1)
axis(1)
box()
legend(
  x = min(biasarray.var.runhour),
  y = length(list.vlevel),
  legend = expname,
  lty = 3,
  lwd = 3,
  col = expcol
)
for (exp in seq(length(expname), 1, -1)) {
  lines(
    biasarray.var.runhour[exp, ],
    seq(length(list.vlevel), 1, -1),
    col = expcol[exp],
    lwd = 3,
    lty = 3
  )
}
abline(v = 0, lty = 3)
```

The plot should end up in the first quadrant with yaxis values increasing from 0 upwards to +###.

Comment: Please make this question reproducible, either by generating random data and reproducing the problem there or giving us a small sample of your data by using `dput(head(list.vlevel))`. You'll also need to either remove other inconsequential variables (e.g., `list.var.bias`, `list.score.bias`, `vv`, `expcol`, `expname`) or give us those, too. (There are a *lot* of missing variables here, I suggest you focus on providing a clear-cut simple example without whole lots of `dput`s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `axis(2, ...)` line draws the y axis. You can see that is the labels follow a descending sequence: `seq(length(list.vlevel), 1, -1)`. `seq(1, length(list.vlevel))`

Similarly, inside `lines()`, *probably* you need to make the same change from `seq(length(list.vlevel), 1, -1)` to ``seq(1, length(list.vlevel))`

That's as much as we can tell with the info you've provided - can't run any of yoru code without values for all the constants you use, e.g., `biasarray.var.runhour`, `list.var.bias`, `vv`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I wasn't sure how seq and axis were related.